# iPhone iOS NSMutableAttributedString editor example

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, text-editor, nsattributedstring

I'm looking at an NSMutableAttributedString example by apple : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreTextPageViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010699-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2 and see that they load attributed strings as XML files.

Are there any examples of how to use a text editor create an attributed string on an iPhone/iPad? I don't want to create attributed string programmatically, but want the user to be able to create an attributed string using a text editor.

Is this kind of work possible?

Answer (score 1):

Mixing three or four answers I have read on this forum, you can do this:

1. Create your own user interface buttons for underline, add color... (I suggest on storyboard, but this is your election)
2. Subclass UITextView and override the drawRect method for display, using CoreText, because you'll need an editable text view. [Here](http://www.a-coding.com/2012/03/syntax-highlighting-in-ios.html) you have how to do it.
3. Create a method for change the attributes to each letter user writes after touching, p.e., the "underline" button.

I hope it helps you!!